# Why does the distance From the Router Affect Internet speed(eg. speedtest.net)?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, bandwidth

I noticed that when i'm just 2feet away from my router, i get my full 50mbps up/down and only get 20mbps when i'm approx 10ft away behind a 2-Inch thick wall.

From my understanding(pls correct me if im wrong), as long as your wireless device is tethered from the AP, then speedtest sites would measure the speed and bandwidth of your service. So why would the speed and bandwidth degrade when my wireless device is farther?

Comment: A chain is only as strong as its weakest link.

Answer (score 2):

In Wi-Fi, the signal strength determines your wireless rate.  This is measured by a negative value called RSSI.  So, as you get further away from the AP, the signal gets weaker, which triggers an algorithm in the AP to use a lower rate, thereby affecting your performance.  Also know that data with higher rates are sent at lower power and data with lower rates are sent at higher power, so that the traffic can reach farther distances (There's a whole science behind this behavior and is outside the scope of this question).  This is the nature of Wi-Fi - As you increase distance, the throughput goes down.
Obstructions such as walls attenuates (weakens) the signal even further.

Comment: You may want to add that neighboring routers on the same channel will change the received RSSI, because the received signal strength index has noise built into the equation. Also, the data rates have nothing to do with power levels, it's just less information on the carrier signal, and less chance to have errored bits per second. I believe some of it has to do with the difference of the method used to transmit on the chipset, dsss, ofdm etc. Regards.

Comment: The algorithm in the AP makes sense and this part doesnt "There's a whole science behind this behavior and is outside the scope of this question"....lol....greatly appreciate the input. Thank you!

Comment: @paul Bogart, your welcome. Also please note, that wall/obstacle penetration is entirely dependant on the frequency (band) that is in use by the router. I.e 2.4ghz vs 5.8ghz. the general rule of thumb for rf frequency is that the higher it is, the less it will penetrate/ the more it attenuates in air. Wireless interference plays a huge part in this. Try switching channels on the router to 1,6, or 11 for 2.4ghz. and anything other than 36 for 5.8ghz

Comment: @PaulBogart - Haha... Tim_Stewart explained "There's a whole science behind this behavior and is outside the scope of this question".  I was just trying to keep it simple for you - But there you have it!

Comment: @Tim_Stewart wow! a plus with the recommendations there...i'll tear down that wall....ah i mean i'll follow the recommendations with the frequency. Thanks again!